# What is the easiest control to use with Child of Eden for Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, child-of-eden

Child of Eden for Xbox 360 can be played with the normal controller or with Kinect.
I like Kinect and always played with it, but I struggle a lot to finish the game: it seems to me that to cope with the speed and precision required you have to be borderline superhuman!
I wonder if my mistake is that I play with kinect and maybe with the normal controller it's easier.... the other alternative is that I'm a really poor player (that is probably the truth! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by easier. It seems to pull the difficulty down slightly when you play Kinect, but that's more than balanced out by how much harder it is to move you arms about than your thumbs.

This game is quite a bit harder than Rez though - the last level's pretty tough with a controller or Kinect. I couldn't beat the last level with Kinect, but I could (just) with the controller.

Comment: Do you use the "standard" Kinect settings? In the game there are quite a few options to fine tune the "sensitivity" of Kinect...

Comment: @Yaztromo I didn't even know those settings were there, so I guess I'm on the defaults.